# Búsqueda sql que retorne todo en un rango de fechas (solucionado)

Tags: mysql, sql

El caso es que necesito traer ciertos datos de una tabla donde el campo fecha este dentro de un rango específico.

La consulta que estoy usando es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabla 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2018-10-29' AND '2018-10-30';
```

la consulta funciona bien hasta que el rango de fechas es demasiado grande, entonces solo retorna unas pocas filas que están a partir de la primera fecha.
Entonces, mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo sería la consulta si quiero *TODOS* los campos que estén en un rango determinado, no importa lo grande que este sea?.

por ejemplo si ejecuto:

```
SELECT venta.*, venta_cliente.cliente_persona_cedula FROM venta JOIN 
venta_cliente ON venta_cliente.venta_codigo = venta.codigo WHERE venta.fecha 
BETWEEN '2018-10-30' AND '2018-10-30' ORDER BY fecha DESC;

/*
+--------+--------+------------+------------------------+
| codigo | precio | fecha      | cliente_persona_cedula |
+--------+--------+------------+------------------------+
|     72 |    370 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     73 |    300 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     74 |    100 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     75 |    100 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     76 |     35 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     77 |    100 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     78 |    100 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     79 |     35 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     80 |     35 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     81 |     35 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
|     82 |     35 | 2018-10-30 |               NULL     |
+--------+--------+------------+------------------------+
*/
```

funciona correctamente, pero si ejecuto:

```
SELECT venta.*, venta_cliente.cliente_persona_cedula FROM venta JOIN 
venta_cliente ON venta_cliente.venta_codigo = venta.codigo WHERE venta.fecha 
BETWEEN '2018-10-24' AND '2018-10-30' ORDER BY fecha DESC;

/*
+--------+--------+------------+------------------------+
| codigo | precio | fecha      | cliente_persona_cedula |
+--------+--------+------------+------------------------+
|     68 |    400 | 2018-10-27 |               NULL     |
|     69 |   2000 | 2018-10-27 |               NULL     |
|     70 |    500 | 2018-10-27 |               NULL     |
|     71 |   2992 | 2018-10-27 |               NULL     |
|     65 |    500 | 2018-10-27 |               NULL     |
|     66 |    400 | 2018-10-27 |               NULL     |
|     67 |    500 | 2018-10-27 |               NULL     |
|     16 |     70 | 2018-10-26 |               NULL     |
+--------+--------+------------+------------------------+
*/
```

Resulto la solución radicaba en el JOIN que estaba trallendo la intersección de las tablas y yo necesitaba usar LEFT JOIN.
La siguiente consulta funciona correctamente:

```
SELECT venta.*, venta_cliente.cliente_persona_cedula 
FROM venta 
LEFT JOIN venta_cliente -- Cambio
ON (venta_cliente.venta_codigo = venta.codigo) 
WHERE venta.fecha BETWEEN '2018-10-24' AND '2018-10-30' 
ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

Comment: en teoria deberia funcionar asi, a no se que el formato de fecha de tu BD sea diferente

Comment: Por favor, compartenos unos ejemplos en el caso que es "correcto" tu resultado y en el que "no". Para entender mejor tu situación.

Comment: deberías observar la configuración de tu motor, a veces limitan la cantidad de filas devueltas, en una consulta, si es así, deberías cambiar los parámetros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La condición que utilizas está bien hecha en tu segundo escenario, está trayendo todas las ventas donde su fecha se encuentre en el rango del '2018-10-24' al '2018-10-30'. Me parece que tu inconveniente se debe a las relaciones. Estás utilizando un **INNER JOIN** hacia la tabla de **[venta_cliente]**, entonces procura que se respete lo declarado en el **on**, que los registros existan en ambas tablas.

Para salir de duda, en vez de utilizar un **JOIN**, cambialo por un **FULL OUTER JOIN** para que así te traiga los datos que no están en ambas tablas. De la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT venta.*, venta_cliente.cliente_persona_cedula 
FROM venta 
FULL OUTER JOIN venta_cliente -- Cambio
    ON (venta_cliente.venta_codigo = venta.codigo) 
WHERE venta.fecha BETWEEN '2018-10-24' AND '2018-10-30' 
ORDER BY fecha DESC;
```

Pruebalo y cuentanos si así aparecen esos registros.

**Nota:** te recomiendo el uso de "alias" al momento de declarar las tablas para que así la escritura y la interpretación no sea tan engorroza.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, resulto que el problema radicaba justo donde dices, no se porque me tira error el shell al poner FULL OUTER JOIN, pero intente con LEFT JOIN que me daría el resultado que necesito, y efectivamente funciona

Comment: Listo @RafaelLópez, un gusto haberte podido ayudar, no olvides dar por válida mi respuesta para así cerrar la pregunta. Suerte!